# Default setting in Vagrant

Tags: dry, vagrant

I have a bunch of boxes configured in one Vagrantfile. What is a good way to DRY up the code so it doesn't repeat certain configuration commands, e.g.:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define 'box1' do |c|
    c.box = "precise64"
  end
  config.vm.define 'box2' do |c|
    c.box = "precise64"
  end
end
```

I would like to do this instead:

```
Vagrant::Config.defaults[:box] = 'precise64'
config.vm.define 'box1' do |c|
end
config.vm.define 'box2' do |c|
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicest way I can think of so far is:

```
def defaults(c)
  c.vm.box = 'precise64'
end

config.vm.define 'box1' do |c|
  defaults(c)
end

config.vm.define 'box2' do |c|
  defaults(c)
end
```